# Django POST does not return all elements of the zipped list

Tags: django, django-views

I have a class view with both get and post methods.  In the get method, I have these items:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(user = the_user)
item_pricing_forms = []         # list of forms
item_component_formsets = []    # list of inline formsets

for item in items:
    item_pricing_form = ItemPricingForm()
    item_pricing_forms.append(item_pricing_form)

    item_component_formset = inlineformset_factory(Item, Component, form = ComponentForm, can_delete = False, extra = item.num_of_components)
    item_component_formsets.append(item_component_formset)
```

then, I zip them into one variable

```
zipped_item_pricing_components = zip(items, item_pricing_forms, item_component_formsets)
```

In my template:

```
<form action = "" method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}

<table>

    {% for item, item_pricing_form, item_components_formset in zipped_item_pricing_components %}
    <tr><th>Item {{item}}</th></tr>
    {{ item_pricing_form }}

    {{ item_components_formsets.management_form }}
    {% for item_components_formset in item_components_formsets }}
        {{item_components_formset }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

    <tr><td>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </td></tr>
</table>

</form>
```

This renders fine in the get request.

However, when the post request is passed, I can only see the last element of each list.  So, if I do assert False somewhere in the beginning of my POST view,  the POST data has the information for the last element of each list (e.g. the last element of it item_pricing_forms and the last item of item_component_formsets.  Why does Django not returning the full list?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you have multiple instance of the same form or formset, you must give each one a unique [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.prefix).

Comment: Right you are Sir!  I totally forgot about prefixing the form.  I don't think you can pass prefix argument to inlineformset though.  So, this works for the list of forms, but how about list of inlineformsets?  I do want to name each inlineformset distinctively, so adding prefix in the form of the inlineformset might not work.  Any idea there?

Comment: [Formsets support prefix as well](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view). Note that `inlineformset_factory` creates a formset class, but your view is not instantiating the formset classes. You pass `prefix` when you instantiate the formset.